# Rearrange values position in chordDiagram() in R

Tags: r, plot, correlation, chord-diagram

I have the following correlation values in R namely ``dat` as follows:

```
dat <- as.matrix(cbind(c(1.0000000, 0.5161944, 0.5190630, 0.3717464, 0.5719125),
                       c(0.5161944, 1.0000000, 0.2549985, 0.8469740, 0.7761113),
                       c(0.5190630, 0.2549985, 1.0000000, 0.2130771, 0.2930945),
                       c(0.3717464, 0.8469740, 0.2130771, 1.0000000, 0.5652874),
                       c(0.5719125, 0.7761113, 0.2930945, 0.5652874, 1.0000000))
)
colnames(dat) <- c(paste0("X",1:ncol(dat)))
rownames(dat) <- c(paste0("X",1:ncol(dat)))
dat[lower.tri(dat)] <- 0
```

and I have created the following chord diagram:

```
circos.par(gap.degree = 0.8)
chordDiagram(dat, transparency = 0.5, scale = T, annotationTrack = c("name", "grid"))

for (i in 1:ncol(dat)) {
  circos.xaxis(sector.index = paste0("X", i), 
               major.at = seq(0, 1, .25), 
               minor.ticks = 0, 
               labels.cex = .5)
}
```

which results in: [image]

However, even though the values are represented in the plot in the correct colour, they are not placed in the correct position in the grid axis. For example the value between `X3` and `X4` is `0.21`, but in the `X4` is placed between `[0.25-0.5)` and in the `X3` is placed between `[0,0.25)` but it should be closer to `0.25` and not `0` as it is displayed. How can I fix the positions??

Comment: I do not really get what you want. Is it to change the width of the chords or to rearrange their position on the axis? Or both?

Comment: To change the position on the axis. In the example that i gave note that correlation between X3 and X4 is 0.21. But in the axis the value is placed in a completely different position. In X4 is placed near 0.5 when it should have been placed a near 0.25.

Comment: But isn't the value 0.21 supposed to be visually conveyed by the relative width of the chord rather than its position on the axis?

Comment: Thats true. However, is there a way to repositioned it, so as to be placed in the range that belongs to?

Comment: That does not sound like a relevant modification to me. What if you had 5 chords with the value 0.20? They would be laid all along the axis, not all bunched around 0.20. You cannot generally place the chords on the axis in a way that matches their width. By default the chords are sorted on the x-axis based on their destination. To me departing from that would only add confusion.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I didn't know that about chord diagram, I thought I was making something wring in my code. Very informative comment!